# Automating Redshift Permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, airflow, aws-glue

I am trying to automate a few SQL queries on Redshift, that are 'triggered' from a user permission.

The queries simply create a view of the table with the filter of a customer_id, create a user with the customer_id and give permission for that customer_id to read the view of the table. This prevents different customers seeing eachothers data and this works nicely when I implemented this manually.

The issue I face is automating this as I am manually doing this in Redshift at the moment. I want to automate this given

What I considered:

1. Redshift - doesn't support triggers.
2. Lambda trigger - Lambda doesn't trigger from Redshift.
3. API gateway - The 'request' is also not an API call so clients will not make an API call for permissions (they are non-technical).
4. Airflow - seems like a big setup for something quite small. But could work.
5. Glue - I am using Glue for the load into Redshift currently. Maybe I can add something in the workflow that gets a distinct list of customer_id's, then runs SQL on Redshift (through a Workflow)?

Any thoughts or suggestions on this please?

Comment: What is the precise issue? Is it the ability to automate the setup, or is it how to trigger the setup script?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein both are the issue, I guess when I meant 'automate' I meant both steps. :)

Comment: So what action triggers this whole process? Is it when somebody registers to an application? Are you granting external people (customers) direct access to your database? That is generally not a good idea, since it can be difficult to control/limit what they do in the database. A preferred method is to grant access to an API that can make requests on their behalf.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - yes external people to the DB. Hence I am creating views and users so they can't see eachother's data. I suggested the API route but the company rejected this. The data has a 'customer_id' column which is unique to the external customer which is what determines the "split".

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a different View for each user, you should **create one View that uses [`current_user`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CURRENT_USER.html)**.

This will return the username of the currently logged-in user. Thus, the query can use the username in a Where clause to limit the rows to those that match their identity.

It would either need a column that contains their username, or the View would need to join a table that can match the username to the `customer_id`.

It would be something like:

```sql
CREATE VIEW foo
AS
SELECT
  ...
FROM table
JOIN users USING (customer_id)
WHERE users.username = current_user
```

Comment: You could have multiple customers querying the data at the same point in time so current_user could be multiple users?

Comment: `current_user` would be set to the username of whichever user is running the current query. So, the results would look different for every user. It does not put data into the View -- it changes the query that the View runs to obtain the data. It doesn't matter if multiple users are running queries -- they would only see "their" data.

Comment: Ah okay I will try this out!

Comment: I suggest you test this concept by creating a new table with `username` as one column, and another column of fake data. Then, `SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = current_user`. You should only see that user's rows. Next, convert it into a View to prove that it shows different data for different users. Finally, apply that concept to your existing tables.

Answer (score 0):

You may use lazy pattern for creating view and permissions. In API-lambda:

1. Check if view for customer id exists. If yes , check if user is
   created and have permission. Then fetch data using customer_id user
2. If view is not created, create it using SQL query, go to step #3
3. if user is not created, create it using SQL query, go to step #4
4. If user permission is not created, create it using SQL query, go to step #1

You have to switch connection between superuser and customer_id user for first request and then it will be using customer_id user for all subsequent requests.

Comment: The issue is that there could be millions of customer_id's in the table... so there would be 1m+ views setup and permissions. That would be fine I guess, but any way to optimise this?